# Xamarin.forms and Azure AD B2C - missing PublicClientApplication.PlatformParameters?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I've been following along with Mayur Tendulkar's blog post: [Authenticate Mobile Apps Using Microsoft Authentication Library](https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-mobile-apps-using-microsoft-authentication-library/), but it seems like the article may be out of date with the current version of the library.  (Latest version of Microsoft.Identity.Client seems to be 1.1.0-preview.

The code in the sample refers to an **IPlatformParameters** interface, and a property of **PublicClientApplication**, **PlatformParameters**.

Neither of which seem to be present in this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has changed since the last updates. follow this link.
[MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native), this has been replaced with "UIParent". hope this helps

Comment: let me know if you have any issues i will be glad to help

Comment: Yes Samuel, thanks.  The sample is delivering the Microsoft login page, not the openid login page which enables local authentication and account creation.  Not clear to me how I get the xamarin app to deliver the same login I see when I load the login URL provided on the Ad b2c page which has the "signup link".  I posted this question as well but no answers do far